# How to calculate the vector address of a node in a tree

Tags: vb.net

suppose i have a tree that have a root node. that root node have 3 child nodes. each child node have 3 child nodes and so on say up to level 4. if i number each node from the root node and numbering from left to right, the root node being number 1 and the left child of the root being number 2, the middle child of the root being number 3 and the right being number 3. on the third level the left child node of the left child node of the root being number 5 and so on. if i have numbers 1 up to 13 and want to put each number into a node numbered the same i.e number 1 gets into the root node, number 2 gets into the left child node of the root and so on. how would i achieve that.
its like i am looking for a way of getting the vector location of each node , and an answer which can work with any number of child nodes and any number of the tree height.

thanks

Comment: this doesn't make much sense. how can you say that a node is the "left", "middle" or "right" one ? provide some code and/or the logic behind your reasoning.

Comment: It isn't very clear what 'vector' might mean.  Work your way inside-out by using the TreeNode.Parent and Index properties.  Until you run out of parents.

Comment: sorry guys maybe i am not very good at explaining scenarios. but what i am trying to achieve is to get an address of a node in terms of the numbers from the root node. e.g to get to node numbered 2 my address is 1--2 and to get to node numbered 3 my address is 1--3 and to get to 5 my address is 1--2--5 and so on. in other words i would want to distribute numbered elements into a node with the same number i.e 1 into the root and so on. let me check how to attach images so that i can attach an image of the kind of tree i am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

hmm you could create a Lookuptable. so you could even define another number of children, calculate all numbers and add their address in a dictionary (int, str). But I guess you are reaching some space limits very soon.

So for only 3 children you could do.. (this smeels so much like a homework...)

```
Private Function getAddress(number As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
  Dim _visited As New List(Of Integer)
  _visited.Add(number)
  Return getAddress(_visited)
End Function

Private Function getAddress(path As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Integer)
  Dim _value As Integer = path(0)
  If _value = 1 Then Return path

  Select Case _value Mod 3
    Case 0
    Case 1
      _value -= 1
    Case 2
      _value += 1
  End Select
  path.Insert(0, _value / 3)
  Return getAddress(path)
End Function
```

recursion is used because it is now known how long that address is, but you could also use a while loop:

```
  Private Function getAddress(number As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim _result As New List(Of Integer)
    _result.Insert(0, number)
    While number > 1
      number = (number + 1) - ((number + 1) Mod 3)
      _result.Insert(0, number)
    End While
    Return _result
  End Function
```

The reason why this method works is the numbering system..
when looking at one path.. (marked with brackets)
you may see that the 'middle' node is always 3 times the number of its parent. So 1. find the middle node (which is easy, because the middle node is the only one which gives mod 3 = 0
If mod 3 = 1 then subtract 1, with mod 3 = 2 then add 1
And then just divide the value by 3 to reach its parent.
continue with it until you reached 1

```
      (1)
   (2) 3 4
 5 (6) 7
17 18 19
```

Oh, and you are not limited by those 3 children trees. This method can be used with any amount of child nodes. always use the second last child node and divide its number by the number of child nodes. The only tricky pert there is to do the calculation of the correct node in one line. in multiple lines it should be:

```
If (number - 1) mod childs = 0 Then
  Return number -1
Else
  Return (number -1) + (5 - ((number -1) mod childs))
End If
```

**Added Text**

So if you start to count from -1, I would build such a function:

```
Private Function AdjustResult(wrongCount as List(Of Integer)) as List(Of Integer)
  Dim _oldStart as Integer = 1
  Dim _newStart as Integer = -1
  Dim _diff as Integer = _newStart - _oldStart 'should be -2
  Dim _newResult as New List(Of Integer)
  For each ele in wrongCount
    _newResult.add(ele + _diff)
  Next
  return _newResult
End Function
```

better do not try to add that function within the calculation. Use a new Method that calls the calculation and then calls the function to correct the results...

```
Private Function getNewAddress(number as Integer) as List(Of Integer)
  'Call old Method
  Dim _result as List(Of Integer) = getAddress(number)
  'Correct results to fit for numbering from -1 instead of 1
  _result = AdjustResult(_result)
  Return _result
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, i did not think that i would be a small piece of code as this one. it is working axactly as i wanted, just need to test with more number of childs.

Comment: i have tested and its working with any number of child nodes, thanks very much.

Comment: how would you modify yo code to count from -1 i.e the root node to be -1 and the first child node to be 0 and the second to be 1 and so on?

Comment: Hi, I think with a different counting the calculation will just become more complex. So I would be relative lazy, and instead of changing the calculations I would add a calculation afterwards.. I will edit my Answer because of formatting

Comment: Thanks very much, i managed to achieve the results that i wanted.